# Initial guess for Newton Raphson Division

Tags: algorithm, division, newtons-method

Trying to use Newton’Raphson method to approximate the roots of `f(x) = 1/x - D`, which would be `x = 1/D`. This gives `x_n+1 = x_n(2-D*x_n)`.

What would be a good initial guess for this? I saw [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm#Newton%E2%80%93Raphson_division) that `x_0 = 48/17 - 32*D/17` works, but I don’t understand where this approximation comes from, and I don’t see how its useful since it only applies for 0.5 < D < 1.  I’m thinking of approximating 1/x with a Geometric Series, but the interval of convergence for that is also limited.

Comment: The why is that there's an assumed base-2 exponent normalization step that reduces the problem to the cases where 0.5 ≤ D ≤ 1.

Comment: What about cases for D outside of that range?

Comment: I guess that you missed the reduction concept. `1/D = 2^k.1/(D.2^k)`, choose `k` appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the blue line to the green curve.

[image]

Comment: I’ve graphed this myself before, I understand that it IS a good approximation. I just don’t understand where it comes from, or how that approximation could potentially be improved—especially since it is only accurate for 0.5 < x < 1.

Comment: @Mailbox: there is no need to precisely justify this approximation (could be least-squares or minmax error), it suffices that it is "good enough" (even the constant 1.33 could be good). The interval (0.5, 1] is on purpose, as it is easy to reduce to this range. Trying to find an approximation in a larger range would be a mistake.